# Unable to call any overload of function `map` with arguments error mule 4.0

Tags: mule-component

While I try to use the batch job component along with the batch step and batch aggregator, get the Unable to call any overload of function `map` with arguments error. Have attached the screenshot of the flow and the code in the transform message component.

[image]

Below is the code for the transform message component

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    Locations: {

            (payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {

            location :{
                  documentStatusCode : "ORIGINAL", //Hardcode Value 
                  documentActionCode : "ADD"

            },

                BasicLocation: {
                                  ORG_LVL_CHILD                  :    payload01.ORG_LVL_CHILD                     default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_CHILD_S                :    payload01.ORG_LVL_CHILD_S                   default "null" ,
                                  ISS_TECH_KEY                   :    payload01.ISS_TECH_KEY                      default "null" ,
                                  TRAN_TYPE                      :    payload01.TRAN_TYPE                         default "null" ,
                                  AUDIT_NUMBER                   :    payload01.AUDIT_NUMBER                      default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_PARENT                 :    payload01.ORG_LVL_PARENT                    default "null" ,
                                  ORG_NAME_FULL                  :    payload01.ORG_NAME_FULL                     default "null" ,
                                  ORG_NAME_SHORT                 :    payload01.ORG_NAME_SHORT                    default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_NUMBER                 :    payload01.ORG_LVL_NUMBER                    default "null" ,
                                  CURR_CODE                      :    payload01.CURR_CODE                         default "null" ,
                                  ORG_IS_STORE                   :    if ( payload01.ORG_IS_STORE  == 'T') "Store"  else "DC"                      ,
                                  DATE_CREATED                   :    payload01.DATE_CREATED                      default "null" ,
                                  DOWNLOAD_DATE_1                :    payload01.DOWNLOAD_DATE_1                   default "null" ,
                                  DOWNLOAD_DATE_2                :    payload01.DOWNLOAD_DATE_2                   default "null" ,
                                  ORG_CLOSED_FR_DATE             :    payload01.ORG_CLOSED_FR_DATE                default "null" ,
                                  ORG_CLOSED_TO_DATE             :    payload01.ORG_CLOSED_TO_DATE                default "null" ,
                                  ORG_COMP_CLOSED                :    payload01.ORG_COMP_CLOSED                   default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_NUMBER_S               :    payload01.ORG_LVL_NUMBER_S                  default "null" ,
                                  ORG_MANAGER_NAME               :    payload01.ORG_MANAGER_NAME                  default "null" ,
                                  OLD_ORG_LVL_PARENT             :    payload01.OLD_ORG_LVL_PARENT                default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_NUMBER_OLD_S           :    payload01.ORG_LVL_NUMBER_OLD_S              default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_OLD_S       :    payload01.ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_OLD_S          default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_S           :    payload01.ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_S              default "null" ,
                                  ORG_TYPE_CODE                  :    payload01.ORG_TYPE_CODE                     default "null" ,
                                  ORG_AR_NUM                     :    payload01.ORG_AR_NUM                        default "null" ,
                                  PRC_BOOK_NUMBER                :    payload01.PRC_BOOK_NUMBER                   default "null" ,
                                  ORG_FRN_CODE                   :    payload01.ORG_FRN_CODE                      default "null" ,
                                  ORG_LVL_ID_S                   :    payload01.ORG_LVL_ID_S                      default "null" ,
                                  SYSTEM_OF_MEASURE              :    payload01.SYSTEM_OF_MEASURE                 default "null" ,
                                  GLN_TYPE_CODE                  :    payload01.GLN_TYPE_CODE                     default "null" ,
                                  GLOBAL_LOCATION_NUMBER         :    payload01.GLOBAL_LOCATION_NUMBER            default "null" ,
                                  ALT_TECH_KEY                   :    payload01.ALT_TECH_KEY                      default "null" ,
                                  ORG_DATE_OPENED                :    payload01.ORG_DATE_OPENED                   default "null" ,
                                  ORG_DATE_COMP                  :    payload01.ORG_DATE_COMP                     default "null" ,
                                  ORG_DATE_DISTR                 :    payload01.ORG_DATE_DISTR                    default "null" ,
                                  ORG_DATE_CLOSED                :    payload01.ORG_DATE_CLOSED                   default "null" ,
                                  Address:{ 
                                            CNTRY_CODE                  :    payload01.CNTRY_CODE              default "null" ,
                                            BAS_STATE                   :    payload01.BAS_STATE               default "null" ,
                                            BAS_CITY                    :    payload01.BAS_CITY                default "null" ,
                                            BAS_ZIP                     :    payload01.BAS_ZIP                 default "null" ,
                                            BAS_ADDR_1                  :    payload01.BAS_ADDR_1              default "null" ,
                                            BAS_ADDR_2                  :    payload01.BAS_ADDR_2              default "null" ,
                                            BAS_ADDR_3                  :    payload01.BAS_ADDR_3              default "null" 
                                  },    
                                  Contact :{
                                            CommunicationChannel :{
                                                                    communticationChannelCode :"TELEPHONE", 
                                                                    communicationValue : payload01.BAS_PHONE_NUMB default "" 
                                            },
                                            CommunicationChannel :{
                                                                    communicationChannelCode :"TELEFAX",
                                                                    communicationValue : payload01.BAS_FAX_NUMBER default ""
                                            }
                                  }                         
                     }

            }    ))

      }       

}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The error thrown....

Unable to call any overload of function `map` with arguments
   ({|ORG_LVL_CHILD: Number, ORG_LVL_CHILD_S: Number, ISS_TECH_KEY:
   Number, TRAN_TYPE: String, AUDIT_NUMBER: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT?:
   Number, ORG_NAME_FULL?: String, ORG_NAME_SHORT?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER?:
   Number, CURR_CODE?: String, ORG_IS_STORE?: String, CNTRY_CODE?:
   String, BAS_ADDR_1?: String, BAS_ADDR_2?: String, BAS_ADDR_3?:
   String, BAS_CITY?: String, BAS_STATE?: String, BAS_ZIP?: String,
   BAS_ISD?: String, BAS_AREA?: String, BAS_PHONE_NUMB?: String,
   BAS_ISD_FAX?: String, BAS_AREA_FAX?: String, BAS_FAX_NUMBER?:
   String, DATE_CREATED?: Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_1?: Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_2?:
   Date, ORG_CLOSED_FR_DATE?: Date, ORG_CLOSED_TO_DATE?: Date,
   ORG_COMP_CLOSED?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_S?: Number, ORG_MANAGER_NAME?:
   String, OLD_ORG_LVL_PARENT?: Number, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_OLD_S?:
   Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_OLD_S?: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_S?:
   Number, ORG_TYPE_CODE?: String, ORG_AR_NUM?: String, PRC_BOOK_NUMBER?:
   Number, ORG_FRN_CODE?: String, ORG_LVL_ID_S?: Number, SYSTEM_OF_MEASURE?:
   String, GLN_TYPE_CODE?: String, GLOBAL_LOCATION_NUMBER?: Number,
   ALT_TECH_KEY: Number, ORG_DATE_OPENED?: Date, ORG_DATE_COMP?:
   Date, ORG_DATE_DISTR?: Date, ORG_DATE_CLOSED?: Date|}, (payload01,
   indexOfPayload01) -> ?) overloads:
    - map(items: Array<T>, mapper:
   (item: T, index: Number) -> R) -> Array<R> reason:   
        - Expecting
   Type: Array<T>, but got: {|ORG_LVL_CHILD: Number, ORG_LVL_CHILD_S:
   Number, ISS_TECH_KEY: Number, TRAN_TYPE: String, AUDIT_NUMBER:
   Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT?: Number, ORG_NAME_FULL?: String, ORG_NAME_SHORT?:
   String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER?: Number, CURR_CODE?: String, ORG_IS_STORE?:
   String, CNTRY_CODE?: String, BAS_ADDR_1?: String, BAS_ADDR_2?:
   String, BAS_ADDR_3?: String, BAS_CITY?: String, BAS_STATE?:
   String, BAS_ZIP?: String, BAS_ISD?: String, BAS_AREA?: String,
   BAS_PHONE_NUMB?: String, BAS_ISD_FAX?: String, BAS_AREA_FAX?:
   String, BAS_FAX_NUMBER?: String, DATE_CREATED?: Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_1?:
   Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_2?: Date, ORG_CLOSED_FR_DATE?: Date, ORG_CLOSED_TO_DATE?:
   Date, ORG_COMP_CLOSED?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_S?: Number, ORG_MANAGER_NAME?:
   String, OLD_ORG_LVL_PARENT?: Number, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_OLD_S?:
   Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_OLD_S?: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_S?:
   Number, ORG_TYPE_CODE?: String, ORG_AR_NUM?: String, PRC_BOOK_NUMBER?:
   Number, ORG_FRN_CODE?: String, ORG_LVL_ID_S?: Number, SYSTEM_OF_MEASURE?:
   String, GLN_TYPE_CODE?: String, GLOBAL_LOCATION_NUMBER?: Number,
   ALT_TECH_KEY: Number, ORG_DATE_OPENED?: Date, ORG_DATE_COMP?:
   Date, ORG_DATE_DISTR?: Date, ORG_DATE_CLOSED?: Date|}.


   Reasons :
            - Expecting Type: Array<T>, but got: {|ORG_LVL_CHILD:
   Number, ORG_LVL_CHILD_S: Number, ISS_TECH_KEY: Number, TRAN_TYPE:
   String, AUDIT_NUMBER: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT?: Number, ORG_NAME_FULL?:
   String, ORG_NAME_SHORT?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER?: Number, CURR_CODE?:
   String, ORG_IS_STORE?: String, CNTRY_CODE?: String, BAS_ADDR_1?:
   String, BAS_ADDR_2?: String, BAS_ADDR_3?: String, BAS_CITY?:
   String, BAS_STATE?: String, BAS_ZIP?: String, BAS_ISD?: String,
   BAS_AREA?: String, BAS_PHONE_NUMB?: String, BAS_ISD_FAX?: String,
   BAS_AREA_FAX?: String, BAS_FAX_NUMBER?: String, DATE_CREATED?:
   Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_1?: Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_2?: Date, ORG_CLOSED_FR_DATE?:
   Date, ORG_CLOSED_TO_DATE?: Date, ORG_COMP_CLOSED?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_S?:
   Number, ORG_MANAGER_NAME?: String, OLD_ORG_LVL_PARENT?: Number,
   ORG_LVL_NUMBER_OLD_S?: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_OLD_S?: Number,
   ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_S?: Number, ORG_TYPE_CODE?: String, ORG_AR_NUM?:
   String, PRC_BOOK_NUMBER?: Number, ORG_FRN_CODE?: String, ORG_LVL_ID_S?:
   Number, SYSTEM_OF_MEASURE?: String, GLN_TYPE_CODE?: String,
   GLOBAL_LOCATION_NUMBER?: Number, ALT_TECH_KEY: Number, ORG_DATE_OPENED?:
   Date, ORG_DATE_COMP?: Date, ORG_DATE_DISTR?: Date, ORG_DATE_CLOSED?:
   Date|}.
    - map(value: Null, mapper: (item: Nothing, index: Nothing)
   -> Any) -> Null reason:  
        - Expecting Type: Null, but got:
   {|ORG_LVL_CHILD: Number, ORG_LVL_CHILD_S: Number, ISS_TECH_KEY:
   Number, TRAN_TYPE: String, AUDIT_NUMBER: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT?:
   Number, ORG_NAME_FULL?: String, ORG_NAME_SHORT?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER?:
   Number, CURR_CODE?: String, ORG_IS_STORE?: String, CNTRY_CODE?:
   String, BAS_ADDR_1?: String, BAS_ADDR_2?: String, BAS_ADDR_3?:
   String, BAS_CITY?: String, BAS_STATE?: String, BAS_ZIP?: String,
   BAS_ISD?: String, BAS_AREA?: String, BAS_PHONE_NUMB?: String,
   BAS_ISD_FAX?: String, BAS_AREA_FAX?: String, BAS_FAX_NUMBER?:
   String, DATE_CREATED?: Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_1?: Date, DOWNLOAD_DATE_2?:
   Date, ORG_CLOSED_FR_DATE?: Date, ORG_CLOSED_TO_DATE?: Date,
   ORG_COMP_CLOSED?: String, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_S?: Number, ORG_MANAGER_NAME?:
   String, OLD_ORG_LVL_PARENT?: Number, ORG_LVL_NUMBER_OLD_S?:
   Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_OLD_S?: Number, ORG_LVL_PARENT_NUM_S?:
   Number, ORG_TYPE_CODE?: String, ORG_AR_NUM?: String, PRC_BOOK_NUMBER?:
   Number, ORG_FRN_CODE?: String, ORG_LVL_ID_S?: Number, SYSTEM_OF_MEASURE?:
   String, GLN_TYPE_CODE?: String, GLOBAL_LOCATION_NUMBER?: Number,
   ALT_TECH_KEY: Number, ORG_DATE_OPENED?: Date, ORG_DATE_COMP?:
   Date, ORG_DATE_DISTR?: Date, ORG_DATE_CLOSED?: Date|}.
```

---

Comment: `map` works with arrays, but it looks like you're passing it an object. What's your payload look like?

Comment: @jerney it all looks like some garbage value when returned

Comment: You'll want to find a way to get an accurate representation of your payload, and include it in your question. That's going to increase the likelihood of someone being able to help you out.